# yarn berry foreach workspaces not building packages in order specified in package.json

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, yarnpkg-v3

In Yarn 1, `yarn workspaces run build` would use the order specified in the `workspaces` field of the `package.json` file to build each package.

For example, if I had the order specified like this:

```json
"workspaces": {
  "packages" [
    "packages/c",
    "packages/b",
```

Then `packages/c` would be built before `packages/b`.

In Yarn 3, `packages/b` is being built before `packages/c` which won't work as I need `packages/c` to be built before everything else.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Start by including the `workspace-tools` yarn plugin:

```
yarn plugin import workspace-tools
```

After doing that you should be able to do:

```
yarn workspaces foreach -pRt run build
```

Which should give you the behavior you want parallelizing builds where it can.